# Search engines for cheapest flight to a specific location from anywhere?

Tags: air-travel, budget, flight-search-engines

I'm looking for a flight search engine that would show me the cheapest flight to a specific destination from anywhere. I know there's skyscanner and google flights to find the cheapest flight FROM a specific destination to anywhere, but this is the reverse.

The use case for this is when I'm dealing with points. The points most of the time have a set value to any location, say, in Western Europe. Then from which I can buy the rest of the ticket with money.

Comment: kiwi.com shows not from anywhere, but from radius which can be very big to destination and can also sort by price. Not exactly what you want but can be sutable in your case

Comment: @pnuts -- I wouldn't count on it -- an airline could very easily price seats on the "to" and "from" flights quite differently, due to time asymmetry of demands in each direction.